# Connecting mobile app with back-end algorithm

Tags: mongodb, mobile, server, database-connection, backend

I'm working on a school project. We have an AWS server set up with MongoDB. We created some user DB for account verification purposes and communicate with it using REST API. What we need is for the mobile app to send some data to the server side. Run it with an algorithm, then return back the result in JSON format. I've never done anything similar to this, so I have no idea how to go about it. If anyone could provide some lead or guidance/links that would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Check answer and let me know if you need any help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need a algorithm for it. It is just a process you have to follow and its kinda lot more easy than you thinking.

If you are doing it in android you can connect to rest webservice via Google's Volley http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html.

Or You can use Retrofit 2.0. I have been using it for a long time and i prefer it. 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I understand how to connect to the server with rest api, but the part I don't understand is how can I set up an algorithm with a end point. So for example, I want to do a simple calculation. Like 1 + 1, I sent from my mobile 1 + 1 in json format to the end point. Then the endpoint would trigger some sort of algorithm, run the data with the algorithm then return back 2.

Comment: In case of json format keep two field in your Model. just add the the two field in mongodb and make a response of it from server.

Comment: The question you are asking that how to build a server that add two fields right?